# Drop down is not clearing a particular Drop down selections

Tags: angularjs

**Problem:** I have a form that looks up Doctors. The user can look up doctors two ways: by entering the name of the doctor/other things or by zip and distance:

[image]

So when the user wants to look based on zip code radius, it will make the drop down and input fields blank on the first option of searching and vice versa.

However, this functionality is not working when if the user enters speciality, city or gender. Meaning, if user decides to use zip code instead after displaying the results, it will not clear prior entries.

As you can see with the image below, the prior entry, which was the city, did not clear up when I tried to look for a doctor based on zip and mileage. How can I achieve this using angularjs. :

[image]

Here is the form:

```
        <form name="providerSearch" ng-submit="SearchProvider(searchParam);" novalidate role="form">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physiciansfirstname" ng-model="searchParam.FirstName" placeholder="First name:" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physicianslastname" ng-model="searchParam.LastName" placeholder="Last name:" type="text" /></div>

        <!---<div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>--->
                <!---<option disabled="disabledvalue=""></option>---><!---<option>Family practice</option><option>General practice</option><option>Internal medicine</option><option>Pediatrics</option>
            </select>--->
            <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>
                     <!---<option value=""></option>--->
                      <cfoutput query="SpFind">
                       <option value=#ProviderSpecialty#>#ProviderSpecialty#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City">
                <option selected="selected" value="">City</option>
                     <!---<option value=""></option>--->
                      <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                       <option value=#trim(city)#>#trim(city)#</option>

                       <!---<option ng-selected="{{searchParam.City==#city#?true:false}} value=#city#>#city#</option>--->
                    </cfoutput> 
            </select>

        <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities" value="{{c.City}}">{{c.City}}</option> </select>--->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!---<div class="col-xs-6 no-right-padding paddingLanguage">
                <div class="form-group widthLanguage">


                <select id="language" name="language" class="form-control" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                    <!---<option value=""></option>--->
                 <cfoutput query="Languages">
                      <option value=#Language#>#Language#</option>
                    </cfoutput> 
                  </select>



                  <!---<select name="language" class="form-control widthLanguage" id="language" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="l in Languages">{{l.Lang}}</option>
                  </select>--->
                </div>
            </div>--->

            <div class="col-xs-6 no-left-padding">
                <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender" ng-model="searchParam.Gender">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Gender</option>
                <!---<option value=""></option>--->
                <option>Male</option><option>Female</option> </select></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="hrDoctor" />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="miles" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance">
                        <!---<option selected="selected" value="" disabled="disabled">Miles</option>--->
                            <option selected="disabled" value=""></option>
                            <option value={{v.value}} ng-repeat="(k , v) in miles track by $index">{{v.value}}</option>
                            <!---<option selected="disabled" value=""></option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="15">15</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>---> 
                        </select>
                        <div class="input-group-addon">mi</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" onclick="return checkTextField(); overlayDisplayButton();" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" />
            <div style="margin-top:10pt"><button type="reset" class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="location.href = 'http://brokers_dev2.rmgtest.com/index.cfm/doctor-finder/';">Clear Form</button></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is what I did to put those fields blank:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $zip = $('#zip');
    var $city = $('#city');
    var $specialty = $('#providerSpecialty');
    var $fName = $('#physiciansfirstname');
    var $lName = $('#physicianslastname');
    /*var $language = $('#language');*/
    var $gender = $('#gender');
    var $miles = $('#miles').val('');

    $zip.on("change",function(){
        $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
        $('#providerSpecialty option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
        $fName.val('').trigger('input');
        $lName.val('').trigger('input');
        $('#gender option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
        //$('#language option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
    });

    $city.on("change",function(){
        $zip.val('').trigger('input');
        $miles.val('').trigger('input');
    });

    $specialty.on("change",function(){
        $zip.val('').trigger('input');
        $miles.val('').trigger('input');
    });

    $fName.on("change",function(){
        $zip.val('').trigger('input');
        $miles.val('').trigger('input');
    });

    $lName.on("change",function(){
        $zip.val('').trigger('input');
        $miles.val('').trigger('input');
    });

    $gender.on("change",function(){
        $zip.val('').trigger('input');
        $miles.val('').trigger('input');
    });

    $miles.on("change", function(){
        $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
        $('#providerSpecialty option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
        $fName.val('').trigger('input');
        $lName.val('').trigger('input');
        $('#gender option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
        /*$('#language option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');*/
    });
```

I am not seeing what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated

Here is what I am seeing when I use the Developer Tool on chrome. On the last entry, the specialty that was selected was not cleared when I selected to look up providers based on zip and mileage:

[image]

Here is the js file @DanielW:

```
    (
function(){
    var $scope, $location;
    var indexApp = angular.module('indexApp',['ui.bootstrap']);

    indexApp.controller('IndexController',function($scope,$http,$location,anchorSmoothScroll){
        $scope.Lang = 'initVal';
        $scope.ShowResults = false;
        $scope.ShowDesc = true;
        $scope.NoResults = false;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.maxPageNumbersToShow = 10;
        $scope.formModel = {};
        $scope.searchMode = 0;
        $scope.miles =  [{'value':'5'},{'value':'10'},{'value':'15'},{'value':'20' }];
        $scope.Specialties = [{'value':'Family practice'},{'value':'General practice'},{'value':'Internal medicine'},{'value':'Pediatrics'}];
        $scope.Gender = [{'value':'Male'},{'value':'Female'}];
        $scope.Languages = {};
        $scope.Cities = {};
        $scope.searchParam = {};
        $("input").removeAttr('disabled');

        $scope.searchParam.Distance = $scope.miles[0];

        $scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
            try{
                var lon, lat;
                // console.log('starting geoposition code.');
                if("geolocation" in navigator){
                    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
                        lat = pos.coords.latitude.toFixed(3);
                        lon = pos.coords.longitude.toFixed(3);
                        // console.log(lat + ' ' + lon);
                        $http.get("/includes/ReturnCurrentZipcode.cfm?Lat=" + lat + "&Lon=" + lon)
                        .then(function(response){
                            $scope.searchParam.Zip = response.data;
                        })
                    })
                }
                else{ console.log('No geolocation'); }
            }
            catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }
        }

        $scope.GetCityList = function (){
            try{
                $http.get("/includes/ReturnCityList.cfm")
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.Cities = response.data.Cities;
                    })
            }
            catch(err){}
        }

        $scope.GetLangList = function (){
            try{
                $http.get("/Brokers-en-us/includes/remote/ReturnLangList.cfm")
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.Languages = response.data.Languages;
                    })
            }
            catch(err){}
        }

        $scope.SearchProvider = function(searchParam){
            try{
                $scope.searchMode = 1;
                var queryString='';
                if($scope.formModel && $scope.formModel !== searchParam){
                    $scope.resultsCount = 0;
                    currentPage = 1;
                }
                if(searchParam){
                    $scope.formModel = searchParam;
                    for(var param in searchParam){
                        if(searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param)){
                            var paramValue = searchParam[param].value ? searchParam[param].value.trim() : searchParam[param].trim();
                            if (paramValue.length > 0)
                                queryString += param + '=' + paramValue + '&';
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(queryString);
                queryString= '?' + queryString + 'currentpage=' + $scope.currentPage;

                $http.get("/includes/ReturnProvidersList.cfm" + queryString)
                .then(function(response){
                    $scope.providers = response.data.provider;
                    $scope.resultsCount = response.data.rowCount;
                    if (!$scope.providers){
                            $scope.NoResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                    else{
                            $scope.NoResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                })
            }
            catch(err){ alert('No response.: ' + err.message); }
        }

        $scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage'], function(){
            try{
                if($scope.searchMode == 1){
                    $scope.SearchProvider($scope.formModel);
                    }
            }
            catch(err){}
        });


        $scope.GetCityList();
        $scope.GetLangList();
        $scope.GetCurrentZip();

        $scope.gotoElement = function (eID){
            //http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y65G5/
              // set the location.hash to the id of
              // the element you wish to scroll to.

            //$location.hash('bottom');

              // call $anchorScroll()
            var browserWidth = screen.availWidth;
            if (browserWidth < 768)
                anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo(eID);
        };

    });

    indexApp.service('anchorSmoothScroll', function(){
        this.scrollTo = function(eID) {

            // This scrolling function 
            // is from http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript

            var startY = currentYPosition();
            var stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
            var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
            if (distance < 100) {
                scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
            }
            var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
            if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
            var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
            var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
            var timer = 0;
            if (stopY > startY) {
                for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
                    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                    leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
                } return;
            }
            for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
                setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
            }

            function currentYPosition() {
                // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
                // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                    return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
                if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
                return 0;
            }

            function elmYPosition(eID) {
                var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
                var y = elm.offsetTop;
                var node = elm;
                while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                    node = node.offsetParent;
                    y += node.offsetTop;
                } return y;
            }

        };

    });

    indexApp.directive('allowPattern',[allowPatternDirective]);
    indexApp.directive('popPopup',[describePopup]);
    indexApp.directive('pop', function pop ($tooltip, $timeout) {
    var tooltip = $tooltip('pop', 'pop', 'event');
    var compile = angular.copy(tooltip.compile);
    tooltip.compile = function (element, attrs) {      
      var first = true;
      attrs.$observe('popShow', function (val) {
        if (JSON.parse(!first || val || false)) {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.triggerHandler('event');
            });
            }
            first = false;
        });
        return compile(element, attrs);
        };
        return tooltip;
    });

    indexApp.filter('PhoneNumber', function(){
    return function(phoneNumber){
        var dash = '-';
        var openParen = '(';
        var closeParen = ') ';
        if(phoneNumber){
            var pn = phoneNumber;
            pn = [pn.slice(0, 6), dash, pn.slice(6)].join('');
            pn = openParen + [pn.slice(0, 3), closeParen, pn.slice(3)].join('');
            return pn;
            }
        return phoneNumber;
        }
    });

    indexApp.filter('Zip', function(){
    return function(zipcode){
        var dash = '-';
        if(zipcode && zipcode.length > 5){
            var zc = zipcode;
            zc = [zc.slice(0, 5), dash, zc.slice(5)].join('');
            return zc;
            }
        return zipcode;
        }
    });

    function allowPatternDirective(){
        return{
            restrict: "A",
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
                return function(scope, element, attrs){
                    element.bind("keypress", function(event){
                        var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
                        var keyCodeChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

                        if(!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowPattern, "i"))){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function describePopup(){
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: { title: '@', content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&' },
            templateUrl: 'template/popover/popover.html'
            };
        }
})();
(function($) {
  // @todo Document this.
  $.extend($,{ placeholder: {
      browser_supported: function() {
        return this._supported !== undefined ?
          this._supported :
          ( this._supported = !!('placeholder' in $('<input type="text">')[0]) );
      },
      shim: function(opts) {
        var config = {
          color: '#888',
          cls: 'placeholder',
          selector: 'input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]'
        };
        $.extend(config,opts);
        return !this.browser_supported() && $(config.selector)._placeholder_shim(config);
      }
  }});

  $.extend($.fn,{
    _placeholder_shim: function(config) {
      function calcPositionCss(target)
      {
        var op = $(target).offsetParent().offset();
        var ot = $(target).offset();

        return {
          top: ot.top - op.top,
          left: ot.left - op.left,
          width: $(target).width()
        };
      }
      function adjustToResizing(label) {
        var $target = label.data('target');
        if(typeof $target !== "undefined") {
          label.css(calcPositionCss($target));
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(label); });
        }
      }
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.is(':visible') ) {

          if( $this.data('placeholder') ) {
            var $ol = $this.data('placeholder');
            $ol.css(calcPositionCss($this));
            return true;
          }

          var possible_line_height = {};
          if( !$this.is('textarea') && $this.css('height') != 'auto') {
            possible_line_height = { lineHeight: $this.css('height'), whiteSpace: 'nowrap' };
          }

          var isBorderBox = ($this.css('box-sizing') === 'border-box');
          var isTextarea = $this.is('textarea');

          var ol = $('<label />')
            .text($this.attr('placeholder'))
            .addClass(config.cls)
            .css($.extend({
              position:'absolute',
              display: 'inline',
              'float':'none',
              overflow:'hidden',
              textAlign: 'left',
              color: config.color,
              cursor: 'text',
              paddingTop: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-top'),
              paddingRight: $this.css('padding-right'),
              paddingBottom: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-bottom'),
              paddingLeft: $this.css('padding-left'),
              fontSize: $this.css('font-size'),
              fontFamily: $this.css('font-family'),
              fontStyle: $this.css('font-style'),
              fontWeight: $this.css('font-weight'),
              textTransform: $this.css('text-transform'),
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              zIndex: 99,
            }, possible_line_height))
            .css(calcPositionCss(this))
            .attr('for', this.id)
            .data('target',$this)
            .click(function(){
                if (!$(this).data('target').is(':disabled')) {
                    $(this).data('target').focus();
                }
            })
            .insertBefore(this);
            $this
                .data('placeholder', ol)
                .on('keydown', function () {
                    ol.hide();
                })
                .on('blur change', function () {
                    ol[$this.val().length ? 'hide' : 'show']();
                })
                .triggerHandler('blur');
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(ol); });
        }
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).add(window).bind('ready load', function() {
  if (jQuery.placeholder) {
    jQuery.placeholder.shim();
  }
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code in JSbin and it worked correctly, could you please post the select values when the template is populated? Or do you have a deployed version of the code where I could test?

Comment: @DanielW: I do not have a way for you to test the code. So when I select, let say foot doctor for specialist, it will show doctor who are speciality in feet. However, when I select zip and mileage, it clears the input but in the debugger, it shows that the feet specialist is still present. So I feel what i have for example for #providerSpecialty option[].... is not clearing the value. It is clearing for the inputs like lname and so on but not for the drop downs selections

Comment: As I see it clears the value correctly (selects the first options with value=''). What debugger do you use? Could you please post a screenshot?

Comment: @DanielW sorry I meant the developer tool and I have posted what I did

Comment: @DanielW Is there another approach I can do to achieve what I want?

Comment: with jQuery you can use the .val('') function to clear you selects, for example: `$city.val('');`

Comment: @DanielW where would that go, for you example that you posted and I have tried something like that but it keeps the prior value

Comment: Please post the remaining part of the doctorFinder.js, it may help to figure out what could be the problem.

Comment: @DanielW Would I need to do the following to clear the value: ng-click="searchParam = {}" and I have posted the js file as requested

Comment: Now I see that it is more an AngularJS related question rather than jQuery. Sorry I cannot help as I am not familiar with angular.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to define additional functionality which will check out the values if those are already in variables like `$zip, $specialty, $fName, $lName`.

Using if conditional statement after the user clicks the search button.

```
$('btn btn-warning btn-block').on('click', function(){

});
```

Define a function if conditional which will verify if the both parts of a search are filled up.
If conditional needs to exist inside the on a button search click event functionality.

```
$('btn btn-warning btn-block').on('click', function(){
    if($zip !=0 && $fName !=0 ){
        confirm('testing functionality');       
    }
});
```

The alert box is in use of to check out if the conditional statement does work properly prior implementing the functionality.
Otherwise check out instead of `$zip !=0`,  `!$zip`.

Apply additional functionality which will execute the click event on clear form button, pass the value to the zip code input field and execute the search button event.

```
$('btn btn-info btn-block').click();
```

Using confirm check out also if the clear form button does clear the values which do exist inside variables.

```
confirm(fName);
```

In case of if values do exist inside variables reassign values to null and store the zip code value into an additional variable.

```
  var $city =  null;
  var $specialty = null;
  var $fName = null;
  var $lName = null;

valueZipAdditional = $('input#zip').value(additionalVariable);
```

Grab the zip code input field and pass the stored value into it.
Use click method to execute search button functionality.

```
$('btn btn-warning btn-block').on('click', function(){
if($zip !=0 && $fName !=0 ){
$('input#zip').value(valueZipAdditional);
$('btn btn-warning btn-block').click();     
}
});
```